# Sierra Window Focus Loss, Caused by SystemUIServer

Tags: terminal, macos, administrator

I've recently updated all of my labs to MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 this summer, and have discovered that they now all exhibit loss of window focus somewhat sporadically.  Using the python scripts that can be found when searching for window focus loss issues, I have narrowed down the culprit to SystemUIServer.

Has anyone else come across this issue and if so, have you found a solution to prevent SystemUIServer from stealing window focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined that my issue was caused by one of our management profiles.  Specifically the profile used to manage Menu Extras.  For now I've pulled the profile off and my associate is working on updating the profile to hopefully fix our problem while still maintaining management.  The profile in question was the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadContent</key>
            <dict>
                <key>com.apple.mcxMenuExtras</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>Forced</key>
                    <array>
                        <dict>
                            <key>mcx_preference_settings</key>
                            <dict>
                                <key>AirPort.menu</key>
                                <false/>
                                <key>Battery.menu</key>
                                <false/>
                                <key>Bluetooth.menu</key>
                                <false/>
                                <key>Clock.menu</key>
                                <true/>
                                <key>Displays.menu</key>
                                <true/>
                                <key>DwellControl.menu</key>
                                <false/>
                                <key>Eject.menu</key>
                                <false/>
                                <key>ExpressCard.menu</key>
                                <false/>
                                <key>IrDA.menu</key>
                                <false/>
                                <key>PPP.menu</key>
                                <false/>
                                <key>PPPoE.menu</key>
                                <false/>
                                <key>RemoteDesktop.menu</key>
                                <false/>
                                <key>Script Menu.menu</key>
                                <false/>
                                <key>TextInput.menu</key>
                                <true/>
                                <key>TimeMachine.menu</key>
                                <false/>
                                <key>UniversalAccess.menu</key>
                                <true/>
                                <key>User.menu</key>
                                <false/>
                                <key>VPN.menu</key>
                                <false/>
                                <key>Volume.menu</key>
                                <true/>
                                <key>WWAN.menu</key>
                                <false/>
                                <key>iChat.menu</key>
                                <false/>
                                <key>delaySeconds</key>
                                <real>1</real>
                            </dict>
                        </dict>
                    </array>
                    <key>mcx_targets</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>user</string>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>PayloadEnabled</key>
            <true/>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.mycompany.menuextras</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.ManagedClient.preferences</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>36b14197-3388-492c-b7a1-cae748143969</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
    <string>Included custom settings: Menu Extras settings.</string>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>MenuExtra</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.mycompany.menuextras</string>
    <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
    <string>My Company</string>
    <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
    <true/>
    <key>PayloadScope</key>
    <string>System</string>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>ae5c4c7c-c354-453b-bd15-d37437b46d2c</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```